# Making customize toolbox using Python in arcgis10.1

Tags: python, arcgis

I would like to create a parameter box as a input, and the code is:

```
param = arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName="TARIKH",
    name="date_feature",
    datatype="Date",
    parameterType="Required",
    direction="Input")
```

and the output would be like this:

```
    out_path = "C:/Last"
    geometry_type = "POLYGON"
    out_name = #DATEINPUT
    result = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(out_path, out_name,geometry_type)
```

The name of new featureclass is based on the data input on the parameters.

Comment: But what is the actual question? What is the problem or error or the output at the moment. Mentioning more information will help others understand your problem and potentially help you.

Comment: I think this webpage will help you: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00150000000n000000